# Ubuntu 19.04 - WLAN switches off although displayed as on in status bar

Tags: wireless, 19.04

I am on Ubuntu 19.04 and since I updated my WLAN keeps switching off after some time. What really confuses me is that in my status bar in the right top corner of my screen, I see the WLAN icon next to the Airplane Mode icon, as you can see.

[image: screenshot]

This is, in theory, not possible, because either WLAN is switched on or Airplane Mode is on, i.e. WLAN is switched off.

What could I do to have a permanent WLAN connection?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a workaround (in my case). Point ping at your gateway while connection is up

`ping 192.168.x.x`

I have a similar (except for 'airplane mode') problem on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, using a Intel PRO/Wireless 4965 [Kedron] (rev 61)
I can connect to my router (TP-Link) with no problem but after a while, randomly the connection drops. It seems like the NM applet does not 'notice' the connection is down.
When this occurs and I set out a ping to my gateway, it does not reply.
However, if I reconnect and set a ping to my gateway while the connection is 'alive' no connection drops occur.

I've more than one router available. But behaviour is the same on 2 of them. ( I did not yet tried the others.)

So I wonder if your connection is down can you:

-Ping your gateway?-

-using a 'cable' and all s'well?-

-Other computers/clients connecting to same router have NO issues?-

If connection is down, what is the output when you run (without the '~$') :

~$ `nmcli general status`

~$ `nmcli -f ssid,freq,chan,signal dev wifi list`

~$ `ip -c monitor`

I've been lookin for a solution for several weeks I noticed that some users were helped by just running:

-`sudo apt update`-

-`sudo apt dist-upgrade`-

Other things to consider (on your router):

-Change the radio-channel from auto to manual-

-Change bandwidth from auto to manual-

-Change 802.11 standard   (try A,B,G only or whatever is there for you).

How to choose a radio channel.

-Use radiobutton 'Disconnect' in NetworkManager Applet (do not disable Wifi)-

-Run -`nmcli -f ssid,freq,chan,signal dev wifi list`- again.-

-Pick a channel You DONT see listed, one far away from you or one not occupied a lot.-